# wxPython: Tablet version

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I want to use wxPython for tablets, is there a version of wxPython for tablets?

Or is there a mode I can use in wxPython which would allow it to be used on tablets?

Just to clarify the controls given are currently not "tablet friendly" and the applications written in wxPython are treated as Desktop applications as opposed to tablet applications.

(I currently have a windows 8 tablet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wxPython will (probably) happily run on a Windows tablet, although it may not look exactly tablet-like. It will not run on Android or iOS devices though. I once wrote a touchscreen application in wxPython and it was a bit of a pain as some of the controls just don't work that great on touchscreens. You will have to use generic controls and possibly roll your own to get the most our of wxPython. I think the scrollbars were probably the worst part of it as I couldn't find any way to make them fatter.

On the other hand, you might want to look at [Kivy](http://kivy.org). It is a Python UI toolkit with mobile in mind. It will probably be more suited to what you want to do, although it may not look necessarily native. PyQt also supports  mobile platforms to some degree...